# How can one reach a web app via incorrect domain?

Tags: iis, server, dns

I'm running a public web app on a certain domain. This is what I found in logs today:

```
2020-10-15 11:24:26.1918 [7] GET http://example.com/ requested from 185.39.xxx.xxx 
2020-10-15 11:24:26.5199 [7] User is null 
2020-10-15 11:24:26.6293 [7] Response.StatusCode SubStatusCode are 302 0 
2020-10-15 11:24:26.6293 [7] Response.RedirectLocation is /Login?ReturnUrl=%2f
2020-10-15 11:24:27.7959 [7] GET http://example.com/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f requested from 185.39.xxx.xxx 
2020-10-15 11:24:27.7959 [7] User is null 
2020-10-15 11:24:27.8859 [7] Response.StatusCode SubStatusCode are 302 0 
2020-10-15 11:24:27.8919 [7] Response.RedirectLocation is https://example.com/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f
```

The `example.com` is an actual record from the logs. It is not my domain. I masked the request IP just in case.

My question is: how is it possible? My only idea is they use custom dns resolver where they assign the the example.com domain to my IP. BUT WHY?

The host is MicrosoftServer 2016. There is no mention of this request in IIS logs.

The code writing these logs is the following (asp.net 4.7.2):

```
    void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        Logger.Debug("Application_BeginRequest");
        Logger.Info(Request.HttpMethod + " " + Request.Url + " requested from " + Request.UserHostAddress);
    }
```

Comment: Check your site bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background If you didn't set a host name to block unwanted requests, then they can come in. Such requests can be easily generated (via PowerShell or similar tools), so no need for a custom DNS.

Comment: You can bind the domain and ip in the hosts file, or obtain the domain name from the DNS provider and bind it to the server ip.